# Hiding TabBar controller

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, xamarin.ios, tabbar

I have this MonoTouch related question, but I think Objective/C programmers can help as well.

I have TabBarController with some tabs. I want my home viewController (which is added to tabBar) to appear without tabBar.
I thought the way to do it was to set HidesBottomBarWhenPushed of that controller to true.

```
homePage = new HomePageController();
homePage.HidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true;

homePage.TabBarItem = new UITabBarItem("Home", new UIImage("Images/Icons/home.png"), 0);
```

However, it seems that this works only in case of using TabBar with NavigationController, i.e. in case we actually push controllers. 
I wonder if there is a way to do it just for simple viewControllers contained in tabBarController.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to set the `hidden` property of the tab bar to YES. (or `true` in MonoTouch)

Comment: Howdy Moshe. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: However, this is not exactly what I tried to get.
When I set hidden property to true, I get white rect on spot of TabBar. I want to be able to put ViewController over that TabBar.
I tried to to bring ViewController to front, since, and correct me if I'm wrong, TabBar has index 1, and ViewController being displayed 0. Sadly, that didn't work.

Any further assistance will be much appreciated.

Comment: You will need to resize the frame of your view as well. I will try to post code later.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that, in fact, you cannot cover tabBar area of tabBarController. You can set hidden property, just like Moshe said, or you can play with opacity as well but can't cover it with anything.
But there's a great alternate solution. You can use modal view, which always has higher index than regular controllers. Therefore, it will cover everything.

```
homePageContent.ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.FullScreen;
        homePageContent.ModalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CoverVertical;

        this.PresentModalViewController(homePageContent, false);

        base.ViewWillAppear (animated);
```